# Remove WooCommerce block styles

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, block-editor

I'm working on a custom WooCommerce theme, and ideally would like to use the stable Gutenberg blocks shipped with WooCommerce. Obviously, instead of over-riding all of their styles with my own to match the design, I would rather remove them to improve page speed. Seems like it should be a simple process, but no result so far. Using this:

```
function mytheme_woocommerce_remove_block_styles() {
  wp_dequeue_style( 'wc-block-style-css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_woocommerce_remove_block_styles', 100 );
```

Do I need to hook it at a higher priority? I would think 100 would be sufficient. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: By the way, where did you add this code? maybe you added in inside a class?

Comment: Not in a class. It’s in a dedicated woocommerce file that’s required in functions.php.

Comment: Try moving the code directly to functions.php, if it works than you are probably not requiring the file

Comment: Everything else in the file is firing, so it’s being required correctly. But tried it in functions.php to confirm…still nothing. Something has to be over-riding it…

Comment: Download [query monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/), this plugin will allow you to see what styles/scripts are being loaded and where they are loaded from. Maybe that way you could find the right action

Comment: Finally got this working by using deregister instead of dequeue. Feels heavy-handed, but it worked, although now WC is logging an annoying error that the stylesheet is missing. Other style sheets dequeued fine, even in the same function, so this must be some opinionated priority issue in the original WC hook that I have yet  to track down.

Answer (score 9):

I found out a working solution with **Woocommerce 8.0.1** in 2023:

```php
function disable_wp_blocks() {
    $wstyles = array(
        'wp-block-library',
        'wc-blocks-style',
        'wc-blocks-style-active-filters',
        'wc-blocks-style-add-to-cart-form',
        'wc-blocks-packages-style',
        'wc-blocks-style-all-products',
        'wc-blocks-style-all-reviews',
        'wc-blocks-style-attribute-filter',
        'wc-blocks-style-breadcrumbs',
        'wc-blocks-style-catalog-sorting',
        'wc-blocks-style-customer-account',
        'wc-blocks-style-featured-category',
        'wc-blocks-style-featured-product',
        'wc-blocks-style-mini-cart',
        'wc-blocks-style-price-filter',
        'wc-blocks-style-product-add-to-cart',
        'wc-blocks-style-product-button',
        'wc-blocks-style-product-categories',
        'wc-blocks-style-product-image',
        'wc-blocks-style-product-image-gallery',
        'wc-blocks-style-product-query',
        'wc-blocks-style-product-results-count',
        'wc-blocks-style-product-reviews',
        'wc-blocks-style-product-sale-badge',
        'wc-blocks-style-product-search',
        'wc-blocks-style-product-sku',
        'wc-blocks-style-product-stock-indicator',
        'wc-blocks-style-product-summary',
        'wc-blocks-style-product-title',
        'wc-blocks-style-rating-filter',
        'wc-blocks-style-reviews-by-category',
        'wc-blocks-style-reviews-by-product',
        'wc-blocks-style-product-details',
        'wc-blocks-style-single-product',
        'wc-blocks-style-stock-filter',
        'wc-blocks-style-cart',
        'wc-blocks-style-checkout',
        'wc-blocks-style-mini-cart-contents',
        'classic-theme-styles-inline'
    );

    foreach ( $wstyles as $wstyle ) {
        wp_deregister_style( $wstyle );
    }

    $wscripts = array(
        'wc-blocks-middleware',
        'wc-blocks-data-store'
    );

    foreach ( $wscripts as $wscript ) {
        wp_deregister_script( $wscript );  
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'disable_wp_blocks', 100 );
```

Comment: Thank you! The entire internet is out of date on this one... damn WooCommerce for this difficulty!

Comment: Brilliant. Couldn't figure out why the usual method was not working in a new WC installation (v8+). This did the trick perfectly.

Comment: This is *completely ridiculous* that we have to do this. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for providing this answer. I am getting fed up every time we run a Google PageSpeed check that our site plummets from 90/100 to 50/100 because WordPress and Woocommerce keep adding bloated trash that we don't need.

Comment: Another thank you from me. Woo is absolutely killing itself for me. It's like the folks at Automattic haven't noticed how important page speed is to the web over the last...twenty years?

Answer (score 1):

after trying all kinds of versions of the dequeue code, this mix is what worked for me:

```
function ca_deregister_woocommerce_block_styles() {
    wp_deregister_style( 'wc-blocks-style' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'wc-blocks-style' );
}
add_action( 'enqueue_block_assets', 'ca_deregister_woocommerce_block_styles' );
```

Answer (score 0):

The dequeue handle is incorrect

it should be `wp_dequeue_style('wc-block-style');` and not `wp_dequeue_style('wc-block-style-css');`

<del>A bit confusing at first i agree, every js and css that was enqued via `wp_enqueue_style` or `wp_enqueue_script` gets a suffix of css/js</del>

Example

```
wp_enqueue_style('swiper', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.4.6/css/swiper.min.css')
```

This will create a `<link>` with an `id` attribute of `swiper-css`, im guessing this is why you thought that in order to dequeue the style you need to do this fundtion `wp_dequeue_style('swiper-css')`. But it should be `wp_dequeue_style('swiper')`

Comment: There's nothing about this on the official docs, and the examples do not do this, are you sure this is a general thing and not specific to a framework or blocks?

Comment: @TomJNowell If you view page source/consle you can see that the `id` attribute of styles and scripts always ends in `-js` or `-css`. If you name your css handle `my-style`, in the front it would be `my-style-css`. This is easy to replicate. I know about this because I had the same problem when I started using wordpress =]. Again, this only happens if you use `wp_enqueue_style` or `wp_enqueue_script`

Comment: that's not the handle though, that's just added to the HTML tags ID to prevent clashes if a script and a style have the same handle, query monitor can be used to inspect the actual handles.

Comment: @TomJNowell Thats what im saying. OP tried to remove `wc-block-style-css` but that handle does not exists. Because wordpress added -css to the end. I'm sure im not explaining myself correctly XD

Comment: can you edit your question to make this clearer? Right now your second and 3rd paragraphs contradict eachother by saying the opposite thing

Comment: @TomJNowell Hows this? can't really think of a better way to explane

Comment: @Buttered_Toast Thanks, good catch...still hasn't resolved, though. Changed to `wp_dequeue_style( 'wc-block-style' );`  but the stylesheet is still enqueued.

Comment: The additional paragraph helps, but the 3rd paragraph still says exactly the opposite of what the 2nd paragraph says, they contradict each other. You state everything "gets a suffix of css/js" but your previous paragraph says they do not. I would recommend removing that paragraph in its entirety and relying on the new additions

Comment: It seems that in WC v8.x (at least) the method OP was trying to use (with or without the `-css` suffix, no longer works. This answer from Dariusz does the trick. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/418033/11064

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this question, and the handle for the block-style is actually
`wc-blocks-style`

From the HTML Head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="wc-blocks-style-css" href="https://c0.wp.com/p/woocommerce/5.6.0/packages/woocommerce-blocks/build/wc-blocks-style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
```

So to dequeue the script, you need to use this.

```
function mytheme_woocommerce_remove_block_styles() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'wc-blocks-style' ); // WooCommerce Blocks
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_woocommerce_remove_block_styles', 100 );
```

Answer (score 0):

i used this and worked for me Tested 100% !
Enjoy
add that with the aid of Code Snippets plugin or manually by adding to functions.php

```
if(!function_exists('kazhol_remove_block_styles_woo')){
function kazhol_remove_block_styles_woo() {
    wp_deregister_style( 'wc-blocks-style' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'wc-blocks-style' );
}
}add_action( 'enqueue_block_assets', 'kazhol_remove_block_styles_woo' );
```

Answer (score 0):

A simplified version of Dariusz's answer to remove WC block style assets for WooCommerce 8+ with future proofing for new blocks would be:

```
add_action(
    'wp_enqueue_scripts',
    function() {
        global $wp_styles;
        foreach ( $wp_styles->queue as $handle ) {
            if ( str_starts_with( $handle, 'wc-blocks' ) ) {
                wp_deregister_style( $handle );
                wp_dequeue_style( $handle );
            }
        }
    },
    999
);
```